# To pass givenname and surname from IdP to SP, where does it have tobe specified in the metadata?

Tags: onelogin

We need to pass first name and last name from IdP to Service Provider, does this have tobe specified in the IdP metadate or in the SP metadata, and how? I can not find OneLogin java properties for this.

Answer (score 0):

They are included as attributes in SAML Assertion which is a part of [SAML Response](https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/examples/response). **They don't have to be included in the metadata**  (but some scenarios may need that).

When you create your custom app in Onelogin (either by using UI or API), you can specify which fields are included in the SAML assertion.

Identity provider sends Response to ACS URL. Behind this URL is service provider's backend service which validates the response (idp, SP, ACl url, StatusCode, session NotOnOrAfter, etc. depending on the needs) and processes/forwards needed values and redirects user to relayState location.

Note: There are also other ways to implement SAML authentication flow and it is possible that SAML response could include only authentication assertion with NameID and attributes are queried afterwards. This may require also adding attribute related fields to metadata.

Comment: So the IdP has to send SAML Response with name info to the Attribute Consume Service URL? Then the processing is asynchronous

Comment: @JoopKaashoek I amended my answer. Unfortunately I am not able to produce any screen captures or configurations because I am not an onelogin user myself. My answer reflects how I have done that by using a different idp service (SAML is a standard, anyway). The sentence stating that you can decide which parameter fields to include in SAML Response, is, however, confirmed from reliable sources.

Comment: Thanks Mark, so the IdP sends a SAML Response to the SP, but it appears to happen via the Attribute Consume Service URL as a separate transaction. So The IdP performs two transactions via two separate url's, which makes the processing complicated.

Comment: Yes, SAML authentication flow is a little bit complicated than using a simple non-SSO authentication flow. And of course the complexity depends on used technology stack. For example, browser applications are not able to work as servers and therefore dedicated saml server/service is needed. 

Does you use case explicitly need using SAML or could you use just OIDC which seems to be simpler?

Comment: It appears that the SAML Assertion that is sent by the IdP to the SP can also contain first name and last name. But where is the SAML Assertion defined? Not in the metadata. If the data can be contained in the SAML Assertion then the Attribute Consume Service URL does not need to be used?  It is a mystery

Comment: The OneLogin service creates the SAML Assertion automatically. You can define the fields which are included in the assertion via One Login UI. OneLogin sends the assertion to the ACS URL and it must be defined in the SP Metadata.

Answer (score 0):

We got the names in the SAML attributes in the assertion sent by the IdP. So no need for the Attribute Consume Service URL etc.